# unix timestamp in php/mysql installation - best MySQL datatype to store this as?

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to figure out the best datatype and size in my DB to store unix timestamps...

In otherwords:

```
INT(32)
```

etc...

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) is a pretty straight-forward choice.  It's implemented as a UNIX timestamp internally, but externally it appears as a date string (e.g. "1970-01-01 00:00:01").

EDIT: To migrate an INT to a timestamp, where `time_test` is the table and `ts` is the original column:

```
ALTER TABLE time_test ADD ts_new TIMESTAMP;
UPDATE time_test SET ts_new = FROM_UNIXTIME(ts);
ALTER TABLE time_test DROP ts;
ALTER TABLE time_test CHANGE COLUMN ts_new ts TIMESTAMP;
```

You may have to tweak it slightly if you care about the column order.

Comment: I see.  I didn't realize that...  Answer me this:  If I'm already set up as an INT, can I just go through and change everything to TIMESTAMP and be good to go?  Do I need to specify a size?

Comment: Now I'm startnig to doubt what I thought I understood.. haha.  I want to continue using the column as a unix timestamp - that is, the bulk of numbers.  When you say "externally displayed" - what does that really mean?

Comment: @Shackrock, if you just do a `SELECT ts FROM time_test` you'll see a date string.  But if you do `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts) FROM time_test;` you'll get exactly the number you put in (no precision loss).  There may be ways to avoid the explicit function call.

Comment: Ahh... I see.  In this case, I think it's best if I don't fool too much with it.  What if I asked this:  What is the ideal INT size for this? haha!

Answer (score 2):

MySql supports Unix timestamps directly as the TIMESTAMP data type.

You have the normal limitations; dates must be from 1 Jan 1970 until 19 Jan 2038.

Comment: What about going beyond 2038... is there no fix to that really yet? ha.